# grid admin limit pagination

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid, pagination

I have problem with pagination in admin grid in manage products and  orders. After log to admin, when I go to manage products grid show me all products in list (default set 20). When I set value for example to 30, pagination work. When I set 20 pagination work also. Pagination not work only directly after log to admin. Do you have any hints? I didn't find nothing in controller in gridAction...

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I had plugin Anowave_view who set my page size. This plugin didn't set default value in xml so if i didn't set value in admin, plugin generate value 0.. This value show me all products. when I set other value all good work.